# Bimodal distribution dispersion

Tags: skewness, dispersion, bimodal, central-tendency

what is the correct way to study the variability of a data set when all the observations are distributed like a bimodal distribution?

For instance, here I identified the two modes as central index. Now I need a dispersion index, but I cannot find an index that can correctly explain this variability.

Does it have sense to split the sample into two different subsamples (because of the presence of two different trends) and to use the SIQR to describe the variability for each trend?

[image]